# Count only a specific subset of elements in a Postgres DB

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with some identifiers that repeat themselves like

```
id
-------
djkfgh
kdfjhw
efkujh
dfsggs
djkfgh
djkfgh
efkujh
```

I also have a list of id's of interest, say `["djkfgh","dfsggs"]`. I would like to count only those values that appear in the list, rather than all the distinct values of the column.

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE`, `IN`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff heh. not very good at sql, and really bad at db terminology. thanks.

Comment: I wonder why do you use this notation - `["djkfgh","dfsggs"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select count(id) from table where id IN(subset);
```